# Split mesh along Bezier curve in Blender 2.75

Tags: mesh

Found this [topic](https://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAAahUKEwiVqMC7rY3HAhXGjywKHYOKDPE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblender.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F6531%2Fsplit-mesh-into-two-pieces-using-bezier-curve&ei=upm_VZXjBsafsgGDlbKIDw&usg=AFQjCNFRxNKguM8gWTD63mTBp7u39WwMiQ&sig2=y0kAexA-R4aQZ939_rTsuw), but my Bleder seems to lack the Knife Project tool. Is there anything alike that in newer versions?

I tried using the Sculpt Tools, but all the Grease Cut does for me is duplicate the part of mesh the curve should split without any cut. I'm splitting multi-part mesh and sometimes need several parts to be split with one curve. Like making jigsaw puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

You have to just select the face you want to add a cut in and Subdivide it, by going (w) and the first option 'subdivide', then for instance you want a vertical cut, so select the horizontal edge and by pressing (x) or (Delete) key and choosing 'Dissolve Edges' you will delete it but with out corrupting the mesh, and then you can use the 'Edge Slide' to position your cut on any position on your face you want. To Edge Slide press  (Ctrl+E) and choose the fifth option from the bottom 'Edge Slide'.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that's definitely not the issue. As I wrote - I need a way to cut mesh along the Bezier curve. Exactly along it. And get two or more pieces of the mesh I cut. Like making jigsaw puzzle.

Comment: Oh, now i got it. Did you try to convert your curve in to a mesh and give your curve some thickness, so then you can use boolean modifier set to difference to cut through your mesh.

Comment: Yup, but not doing exactly what it should - causes the part of the mesh on the "inner" side of the converted curve to be lost. It can be got around by using the same ex-curve on two copies of the same object I guess, but it's no way convenient... Guess I could write a script doing it for me, but maybe there's already one around here?